# Bibtex missing .aux file and error codes

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, errors, citing, multiple-citations

Below I have attached my code for a report i am writing along with the error codes it is giving me AND the "lab2bib.bib" file that i am using. I am having so many issues with getting bibliographies to work.... PLEASE HELP. When i run the .bib file it tells that it cannot find the lab2bib.aux file as well.

The following code shows (most of) the documents's preamble as well as an excerpt from the paragraph that contains a `\cite` instruction.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\input kvmacros % For Karnaugh Maps (K-Maps)
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{graphicx} % For images
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{float}    % For tables and other floats
\usepackage{verbatim} % For comments and other
\usepackage{amsmath}  % For math
\usepackage{amssymb}  % For more math
\usepackage{fullpage} % Set margins and place page numbers at bottom center
\usepackage{listings} % For source code
\usepackage{subfig}   % For subfigures
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color} % For colors and names
\usepackage{hyperref}           % For hyperlinks and indexing the PDF
\hypersetup{ % play with the different link colors here
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue % set to black to prevent printing blue links
}

\begin{document}  % START THE DOCUMENT!

The capillary action of \dots\ in greater surface tension. \cite{Nobody06}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{lab2bib}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`lab2bib.bib` file:

```
@misc{ Nobody06,
       author = "Nobody Jr",
       title = "My Article",
       year = "2006" 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please state more explicitly what you do when you “run the bib file”.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of making your code a lot more 'minimal', to focus it on the topics of creating citation call-outs and a formatted bibliography. Please compile this greatly condensed version of your document and check if you still encounter bibliography-related problems. Hint: One red flag is that you're loading the `apacite` package and the `plain` bibliography style; this cannot go well. If one loads the `apacite` package, one should employ the `apacite` bibliography style. Conversely, if you need to employ the `plain` bib style, you should load the `cite` package.

Comment: Off-topic: A suggestion - please get rid of the `\vspace{3mm}` statements at the ends of all paragraphs and, instead, issue the directive `\setlength\parskip{3mm}` in the preamble.

Comment: You need to run BibTeX. But you do not run BibTeX on the `.bib` file, you need to run BibTeX on the name of your main `.tex` file (actually on the `.aux`, butv your editor should take care of that). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864.

Comment: by using the cite package and plain style, i was able to get it working. the apacite package would not work at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved in comments.